# get_absolute_url not working- version 1.4.3

Tags: django

Im trying to use get_absolute_url method within my object but while Im referencing it , it fails,
I have given all the code below

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True,help_text='Unique value for product page URL created from name')
    description = models.TextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    meta_keywords = models.CharField("Meta Keywords",max_length=255,help_text="comma-delimited set of SEO Keywords for meta tag")
    meta_description = models.CharField("Meta description",max_length=255,help_text="Content for description meta tag")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'categories'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('catalog_category',(),{'category_slug':self.slug})
```

context_processor.py

```
from ecomstore.catalog.models import Category
from ecomstore import settings

def ecomstore(request):
    return {'active_categories':Category.objects.filter(is_active=True),
            'site_name':settings.SITE_NAME,
            'meta_keywords':settings.META_KEYWORDS,
            'meta_description':settings.META_DESCRIPTION,
            'request':request}
```

category_list.html

```
<h3>Categorie</h3>

{% for c in active_categories %}
    <a href="{{ c.name }}">{{c.name}}</a><br/>
    <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}" class="category">{{ c.name }}</a><br /> 
{% endfor %}
```

Error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.4.3
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'ecomstore.catalog',
 'ecomstore.utils',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Template error:
In template C:\python27\django-projects\ecomstore\ecomstore\preview\templates\tags\category_list.html, error at line 5
   unexpected end of pattern
   1 : <h3>Categorie</h3>


   2 : {{active_categories}}


   3 : {% for c in active_categories %}


   4 :  <a href="{{ c.name }}">{{c.name}}</a><br/>


   5 :  <a href=" {{ c.get_absolute_url }} " class="category">{{ c.name }}</a><br /> 


   6 : {% endfor %}


   7 : 

Traceback:
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\Django-projects\ecomstore\ecomstore\catalog\views.py" in index
  8.     return render_to_response(template_name,locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts\__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  176.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  155.         return self.render_template(self.template, context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render_template
  137.         output = template.render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  823.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  185.                         nodelist.append(node.render(context))
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py" in render
  84.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  571.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  721.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  772.                             current = current()
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in _curried
  11.         return _curried_func(*(args+moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in get_absolute_url
  883.     return settings.ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES.get('%s.%s' % (opts.app_label, opts.module_name), func)(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\__init__.py" in inner
  35.         return reverse(bits[0], None, *bits[1:3])
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  476.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  363.         possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  276.             self._populate()
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  253.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  276.             self._populate()
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  243.             p_pattern = pattern.regex.pattern
File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in regex
  162.                 compiled_regex = re.compile(self._regex, re.UNICODE)
File "c:\python27\lib\re.py" in compile
  190.     return _compile(pattern, flags)
File "c:\python27\lib\re.py" in _compile
  242.         raise error, v # invalid expression

Exception Type: error at /
Exception Value: unexpected end of pattern
```

Comment: The problem is in your URL regex, which you haven't posted.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel has indicated, there is a problem in one of your URL regular expressions so check your `urls.py` for signs of an invalid regex.  Your stack trace indicates that an expression has been started but not terminated correctly.  One example of an unexpected end of pattern is a character set without a terminating close bracket like `r'foo[0-'`.

Also, the [`permalink` decorator is no longer recommended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator), use `reverse` instead.

You might be able to rewrite your `get_absolute_url` like this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('catalog_category', kwargs={'category_slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: -1 The permalink decorator is indeed deprecated, but if you're using it, returning a tuple is exactly the right thing to do, as it converts it into a URL.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you, you're right.  I didn't read the stack trace correctly.  Answer updated.